# PHP mysql Undefined index: timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me. I am facing error as Undefined index: timestamp in line 24  Not sure What i'm missing. :(
Any help is appreciated!  Thanks in advance

```
$mysql_connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pword, $db_name);
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%d-%m-%Y') from statistics";
if (!$mysql_connect)
die("unable to connect to database: " . mysql_error());

@mysql_select_db($db_name) or die( "Unable to select database");

$result = mysql_query($query);
$response = array();
$stats = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$stats[] = array (
    'date' => $row ['timestamp']
); 
} 

$Response['stats'] = $stats;

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($Response));
fclose($fp);

die ("Failed to execute Query: " . mysql_error());

mysql_close($mysql_connect);

/*$views = mysql_fetch_array($result);
print("<pre>");
print_r($views);
print("</pre>");*/

?>
```

Comment: try this `"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%d-%m-%Y') AS timestamp from statistics"` (dang text formatting messed it up >.<)

Comment: Maybe you forgot to alias your field, now it will most likely be called `DATE_FORMAT(\`timestamp\`,'%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: @sharky this worked thanks! now get an error as failed to execute query.. what is that i'm going wrong in??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to alias your field

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%d-%m-%Y') AS "timestamp"
FROM statistics
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a ton ..This worked..I dont get that error.. 
Looks like something else is wrong in my code..  getting a new error as **Failed to execute Query:**